# Pojo genrated by Hibernate Tools in Eclipse missing @Entity, @Id annotations

Tags: java, hibernate

What settings do I have to set in hibernate configurations, in order for these annotations to appear in the auto-generated pojo?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a concise hibernate configuration file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:DSE</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">user</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">MYSCHEMA</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

To read on look at [this](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/).

Answer (score 0):

In Hibernate Code Generation Configurations -> Exporters tab, need to check "Generate EJB3 annotations".